# Не обнуляется таймер, выдает ошибку, почему?

Tags: javascript

Я запускаю цикл, условие повторяется проверяя нужное мне значение, но при получении ответа true, цикл не обнуляется, выдает ошибку "ReferenceError: timer is not defined", почему? Как можно решить данную проблему?

```
function sboot() (  
    if(условие)
    {
        clearInterval(timer);
    };
); //условия для повторения

function sfinboot() {var timer =  setInterval(sboot, 2000);}; //функция цикла

sfinboot() //запуск
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема из-за видимости переменной timer, функция sboot её не видет, надо вынести и всё должно заработать! 
Не забывайте про область видимости переменных :)

```
var timer;
function sboot() (  
    if( условие) { 
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
);
function sfinboot() {
    timer =  setInterval(sboot, 2000);
}; //функция цикла
sfinboot() //запуск
```

Comment: Либо постоянно его передавать

Comment: Спасибо большое, все заработало